# HTML5 video/audio volume in browsers

Tags: audio, browser, html5

If I open a webpage with an embedded soundcloud / youtube player, it shouts at me at 200% volume (I have 100W speakers, so nearly jumped out the window when happened), but if I navigate to the soundcloud.com / youtube.com sites and use the  player there, it uses the proper, systemwide volume level. I can reproduce it in Edge, Chrome. The fun thing is, that any other media app (iTunes, RadioSure, VLC) tolerates the base volume level, never shouts, just the html5 content.

I have a Realtek HiDef onboard chip, and no knobs in the Volume mixer, just Speakers / System sound. All settings are in default, no "blow my brains out" checkbox are active.

Any hints on debugging?

Comment: You can try turning off [audio enhancements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/fix-sound-problems#v1h=tab05) and see if this helps.

Comment: @DavidPostill : tried with both audio enhancements on and off, and no luck.